# How to start new service in run() of Thread?

Tags: android

How To start new service in Thread...
Thread is running continuously but the startservice() method in run() is not gets started...
Please Help Me.

The code is as follows.....

```
package com.example.demo;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Act extends Service {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate() {
super.onCreate();
Toast.makeText(Act.this,"In On Create",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HelloService.class);
startService(i);
Toast.makeText(Act.this,"In End Create",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
updateTimeTask.start();
}

private Thread updateTimeTask = new Thread() {
public void run() {
    Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HelloService.class);
    startService(i); //This Service not gets started
}
};

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: how did you conclude that it didn't get started?

Comment: Do you have a Log statement that doesnt get logged from the service? Is this how you know the service was not ran? Also post your Manifest. Make sure you declare it

Comment: I added an Toast in HelloService.java file and this toast not gets displayed....and if i call service outside the Thread then that Toast gets displayed....

Answer (score 0):

You must have a Pending Intent for this:

```
// start something with Intent
            Intent widgetUpdate = new Intent(SomeClass.this,
                    SomeService.class);
            widgetUpdate.putExtra("Something", something);

            // make this pending intent unique
            widgetUpdate.setData(Uri.withAppendedPath(
                    Uri.parse(mUriSchemaId + "://widget/id/"),
                    String.valueOf(appWidgetId)));
            PendingIntent newPending = PendingIntent.getService(
                    getApplicationContext(), 0, widgetUpdate,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
remoteview.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.someview,
                    newPending);
```